# How can I remove "-" from all instances in a specific column?

Tags: r, string, variables

I have been trying to remove all instances of "-" from my code. I used the command `gsub("-","", dataframe$column)` with no avail. It doesn't show any errors, but it fixes a few instances and not all. The text is encoded in UTF-8. 
There are different ways that the "-" is written, including spaces and packed dashes. For example.

```
Other --
Other- - -
```

The current text is something like:

```
- - - Other 
- - Other   
- Other
```

I want the results to be like

```
Other
Other
Other
```

Thank you.

Comment: The correct answer depends on the nature of that column. Is it a factor or character column? Please read [MCVE] and do an SO search on "How to make a great R example".

Comment: Also depends on exact characters you are matching. Several characters look like `-` but are encoded differently (minus, hyphen, dash, en-dash, ...).  see http://jkorpela.fi/dashes.html

Comment: It is a character column.

Comment: @Mons your still searching for an answer, which implies that mine doesnt suit you.
Can you please tell me why. Based on your description of the problem it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gsub(" *-+ *", "", "- - - Other")
```

It finds all substrings of the form:

```
Zero or more empty spaces, followed by

one or more minuses, followed by 

zero or more empty spaces
```

and removes them from the string

Answer (score 0):

library(stringr)
str_remove_all(string, "-| ") or
str_remove_all(string, "[:blank:]|[:punct:]")